# How to search an item from listview ? i have items in listview from Server URL

Tags: android, listview, search, android-listview

I am using this `addTextListener` and after `onclicking` on the `edittext` its not searching. Please help me.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {



            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (0 != editText.getText().length()) {
                    String spnId = editText.getText().toString();
                    setSearchResult(spnId);
                } else {
                    setData();
                }
            }
        });

        setData();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this to show filtered data from search text : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/ - works for me